# PlatformNotSupportedException when calling LdapConnetion.Disconnect

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core, novell

Everything appears to be working fine (apart from the fact that retrieving a specific attribute should be way easier than iterating around all existing attributes - not sure why it was designed this way), but when I try to disconnect I get

> PlatformNotSupportedException: Thread abort is not supported on this platform.

The code is pretty much exactly as taken from the Novell documentation, apart from the fact that I am trying to just retrieve 2 specific attributes (name and logon time):

```
var users = new List<User>();

// Creating an LdapConnection instance 
LdapConnection ldapConn= new LdapConnection();

//Connect function will create a socket connection to the server
ldapConn.Connect("DOMAIN.com",389);

//Bind function will Bind the user object Credentials to the Server
ldapConn.Bind("DOMAIN\\_Bassi","password");

// Searches in the Marketing container and return all child entries just below this
//container i.e. Single level search
LdapSearchResults lsc=ldapConn.Search("OU=Users,OU=MCS,OU=AU,OU=COMPANY,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com",
                LdapConnection.SCOPE_ONE,
                "objectClass=*",
                null,
                false);

while (lsc.hasMore())
{
    var user = new User();

    LdapEntry nextEntry = null;
    try 
    {
        nextEntry = lsc.next();
    }
    catch(LdapException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.LdapErrorMessage);
        // Exception is thrown, go for next entry
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + nextEntry.DN);

    LdapAttributeSet attributeSet = nextEntry.getAttributeSet();
    System.Collections.IEnumerator ienum =  attributeSet.GetEnumerator();

    var atts = attributeSet.ToArray().ToList();

    while(ienum.MoveNext())
    {
        LdapAttribute attribute=(LdapAttribute)ienum.Current;
        if(attribute.Name == "sAMAccountName")
        {
            user.UserName = attribute.StringValue;
        } 
        else if(attribute.Name == "lastLogonTimestamp")
        {
            user.LastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime(long.Parse(attribute.StringValue));
        }
    }

    users.Add(user);
}

ldapConn.Disconnect();
```

And as soon as `Disconnect` is called I get the error.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what might be going wrong?

**stacktrace**

```
System.Threading.Thread.Abort()


Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.Dispose(bool disposing, string reason, int semaphoreId, InterThreadException notifyUser)


Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.destroyClone(bool apiCall)


Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.Disconnect()


LogonChecker.Managers.ActiveDirectory.GetADUsers() in ActiveDirectory.cs
- 
64.                    }
65.                }
66.
67.                users.Add(user);
68.            }
69.
70.            ldapConn.Disconnect();
71.
72.            return users;
73.
74.            // LdapConnection ADconn = new LdapConnection();
75.            // ADconn.Connect("DOMAIN.com", 389);
76.            // ADconn.Bind("DOMAIN\\_Bassie", "password");


LogonChecker.Controllers.UserController+<Index>d__2.MoveNext() in UserController.cs
- 
20.        }
21.
22.        // GET: User
23.        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
24.        {
25.            var ad = new ActiveDirectory();
26.            var users = ad.GetADUsers();
27.
28.            return View(users);
29.            // return View(await _context.User.ToListAsync());
30.        }
31.
32.        // GET: User/Details/5


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()


System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: The Novell library was designed for Mono, so it probably does not work very well on .NET Core. You should report to Mono guys and see how they respond, https://github.com/mono/mono/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Novell developers have come up with the [new version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/3.0.0-beta4) of **Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard** which appears to be fully compatible with DotNet Core 2.0. I have changed my project reference to 
Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard 3.0.0 version and now it is working fine.

**Command Line for same is:**

```
Install-Package Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard -Version 3.0.0-beta4
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it throws this error is because `Thread.Abort()` is not supported in .NET Core.
The library will need to be updated to use a different mechanism (I believe CancellationToken is the recommended method)